# disctinctcount from another dataset having multiple grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have report that generates number of policies from 2 datasets.

the table is linked to dataset1.

i used the formula

```
CountDistinct(Fields!Policy_ID.Value)
```

my problem is how to get distinct count for the field Policy_ID from the second dataset "AccountingV10Dataset", specially that i have grouping Contract_Start_Month, Contract_Cover_Type, and Primary_LOB.

below a screen shot to the report design to help you to understand my request
[image]

the report should be generated as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved this way:

i created the below code to calculate disting count from another dataset:

```
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()

Public Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object(),ByVal CountSum As String) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If

Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
Dim PolId as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
PolId = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
If (CountSum = "SUM") then
ct += 1
Else If (PolID <> Convert.ToInt32(item)) then 
ct += 1
END If
PolId = Convert.ToInt32(item)
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else If(CountSum = "SUM") then return suma else return ct 
End Function


Public Function GetMyVal() as Decimal
GetMyVal = suma 
End Function
```

and i call this function by:

```
=code.SumLookup(Lookupset(Fields!Contract_Start_Month.Value & "-" & Fields!Contract_Cover_Type.Value & "-" & Fields!Primary_LOB.Value,Fields!Contract_Year_Start_Month.Value & "-" & Fields!Cover_Type.Value & "-" & Fields!LOB.Value,Fields!Layer_ID.Value, "AccountingV10Dataset"),"COUNT")
```

Hope my solution will helpfull for other users as it did for me.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would derive the Distinct Count back in the Dataset layer e.g. in SQL.  The SSRS Aggregate Functions only go so far.